# ASP .NET MVC Validation on Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

There are multiple controllers in my application. I have a scenario that certain controllers are not allowed to be loaded/ accessed by user until a criteria is satisfied. e.g. There is a `PaymentController` and a `afterPaymentController`, now if I write `afterPaymentController` in URL like afterPaymentController/index it returns the view, What I want is to first validate if Paymnet is made and then if true that controller is loaded.

There are multiple View in Single Controller,almost all require this check.

Note that there are more than 10 controllers which all require this check.

How this can be accomplished in ASP.NET MVC.

```
public class PaymentController : Controller{

 public View Index(){
     View();
   }
}

public class afterPaymentController: Controller{

 public View Index(){
   // I can add a check here that if payment is not made
   // redirect to PaymentController but I have multiple number of 
   //controllers 
   // so any good solution here
    View();
   }
}
```

if someone write the url while he is at Payment/Index and replace it by afterPayment/index he gets redirected to afterPayment.

Comment: "that controller is loaded"...what do you mean by "loaded", exactly? A controller is a class. Do you really mean that a user should not be able to run a specific Action method (within a controller) until some other condition has been met? Please clarify. It would also help to give a specific example and some sample code. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway it seems like maybe some kind of custom Action Filter could be useful here, to run code which checks if the specific payment has been validated or not. But a lot more info would be required from you in order to suggest a specific, detailed solution.

Comment: @ADyson question is edited if its more descriptive now

Comment: Thanks. If you need to apply this in multiple places then I think either a) make a separate class and method to carry out this check, which you can then call from all your relevant action methods, or, implement the same thing but using an Action Filter which you can then apply to all the relevant actions (or whole controllers, if you prefer). That way you get a re-usable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Filters: [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and create a specific logic to be executed before the Action.

Another aproche is use Policy in controller to specify the allowed criteria: [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I have used these approach, the issue i am facing that the 2 overridden functions(ActionExecuting and ActionExecuted) are being called multiple times while the request is in execution. I need it be called once in the request. How it can be achieved.

Answer (score -2):

You can make a flag variable of int type and increment a variable when certain controller is visited and also don't forget to put it in session because in every controller you have to get the flag value from session and make a condition in every controller to check it(flag value).
If certain condition does not met then use RedirecttoAction("home","home")

Comment: the controller being visited doesn't sound sufficient for this purpose. OP needs to validate that a payment was made. Just visiting the payment action doesn't mean that the payment actually happened - it could easily be rejected. Also it doesn't take into account that there could easily be multiple payments transacted within a single user session. This is a very naive and simplistic approach.

Comment: "I have a scenario that certain controllers are not allowed to be loaded/ accessed by user until a criteria is satisfied."   that is the question if certain user tries to visit it then if he had done the payment then allowed otherwise redirecttoAction("specified","specified")

Comment: My logic is to solve the problem by making a variable(int type) putting it in session and then making further procedure to check it. By putting in session, we can access it in other controllers also

Comment: I understand your logic. But your logic is wrong.  a) The specific payment will either be made or not made. So a simple true/false boolean is sufficient. An integer count is not required. b) you are not accounting for the possibility for multiple payments. Better to simply get the payment ID and then check the database to see if it was authorised or not. Then no need for Session either. c) You are assessing the wrong criteria - "validate if Paymnet is made" (as per the question) is not the same as "when certain controller is visited" (as per your suggestion).